# How to run something insert mode, get user input then return to insert mode?

Tags: vim, vimrc

I have `inoremap <C-d> <C-o>:%s/\<<C-r><C-w>\>\C//g<Left><Left>`, which works great (emulating sublime text's find-all multi cursor more or less).

However it leaves me in normal mode, is there anyway I can have it use the input function instead so it would put me back into insert mode?

Comment: 1. Don't ry to emulate your previous editor. 2. Don't stay in insert mode.

Comment: @romainl I agree with both your points, however I prefer to use it a certain way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some more digging I found https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15273810/remap-key-and-get-user-input and ended up adopting it in a way:

```
function! PoorMultiCursor()
    let word = expand('<cword>')
    if strlen(word) > 0
        call inputsave()
        let repl = input('replace "'.word.'" with: ')
        call inputrestore()
        if strlen(repl) > 0
            execute '%s/\<'.word.'\>/'.repl.'/g'
        endif
    endif
endfunction


" sublime text's ctrl+d / alt+f3 (find all)
inoremap <C-d> <C-o>:call PoorMultiCursor()<cr>
nnoremap <C-d> :call PoorMultiCursor()<cr>
vnoremap <C-d> :call PoorMultiCursor()<cr>
```